# Avoid redirect when calling WCF service with forms authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to unit test my web service by calling some methods on it, but I keep hitting the  login page redirect instead of getting an actual result.

I first make a call to my security service which returns a cookie, I can then reuse that cookie to make a call to my other web service. I thought this was the way to go to avoid the redirect.

```
string sharedCookie;

var securityWebService = new SecurityWebServiceClient(CreateCustomBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/SecurityWebService.svc"));
using (new OperationContextScope(securityWebService.InnerChannel))
{
    securityWebService.Login("UserName", "Password");

    var response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
    sharedCookie = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
}

var webService = new WebServiceClient(CreateCustomBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/WebServiceWithFormsAuthentication.svc"));

using (new OperationContextScope(webService.InnerChannel))
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    request.Headers["Cookie"] = sharedCookie;
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = request;

    var data = webService.GetSomething();
}
```

The error is the following:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/WebServiceWithFormsAuthentication.svc that could accept the message.
```

The inner exception is a `404` not found with a `ResponseUri` corresponding to the login redirect url. If I disable forms authentication, the call correctly goes through.

My questions are:

1. How can I verify that my cookie is correctly received?
2. How can I check why it is being rejected and that I am being redirected to the login page?
3. Are there any other leads I could follow to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** For the weirdest reason, if I recycle my app pool in IIS right before making both calls to the web services, they correctly go through without being redirected.

**EDIT 2:** It seems that it works after I've recycled the app pool because the session id cookie has not yet been created. In the response, it appears after my authentication cookie. On any subsequent calls, the session id cookie appears first, and it looks like my second web service doesn't like seeing that session id cookie appearing first...?

**EDIT 3:** My authentication service has sessions enabled, and my normal web service doesn't. It seems like the second one doesn't like it when the session cookie appears first in the header. Maybe it doesn't expect seeing another cookie first?

Comment: How is your cookie being made? By using `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication` methods, or custom?

Comment: We are creating an HttpCookie like this: `new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(myFormsAuthenticationTicket))`

Comment: Certainly looks legit. No further ideas why it would just change format on you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what I did to make it work. It seems weird that I have to do this, so if anyone has a better solution, I'd like to hear it.

The security web service is returning two cookies in the response header. One is the session cookie, the other one is the authentication cookie. What I did was parse the header in a cookie container to extract only the authentication cookie to send only that one to the other web service.

```
string sharedCookie;

var securityWebService = new SecurityWebServiceClient(CreateCustomBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/SecurityWebService.svc"));
using (new OperationContextScope(securityWebService.InnerChannel))
{
    securityWebService.Login("UserName", "Password");

    var response = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
    var cookieHeader = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
    var container = new CookieContainer();
    container.SetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"), cookiesString);
    var cookies = container.GetCookies(new Uri("http://localhost"));

    var authCookie = cookies["nameOfAuthCookie"];
    if (authCookie != null)
         sharedCookie = authCookie.ToString();
}
```

This worked perfectly.